# Warning error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null php

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest

From javscript code I am comsuming an api rest using a fectch but I receive this error:

Warning error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null php

This api has been made in php. If I call this api from soap ui work fine but when I call this api from javscript code receive the error:

This is the javsacript code:

```
function compareValueKey(numInput) {

    let digit_key = document.getElementById("input_compare" + numInput).value;
    
    let configFetch = {
        method: "POST",
        body: "digit_key=" + digit_key + "&numInput=" + numInput,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urleancoded'}
    };

    let promesa = fetch("compareValueKey.php", configFetch);
    promesa.then(function(response){
        if(response.ok){
            console.log("Respuesta OK");
        }
        response.json().then(
            function(objectoJSON){
                let valido = objectoJSON.valido;
                let numInput = objectoJSON.n;
                document.getElementById("input_compare"+ numInput).nextElementSibling.innerHTML = valido;
            });
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.log('Error con la peticion' + error.message);
        });
}
```

This is php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$key =1111;

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$digit_key  =  $data['digit_key'];

$numInput  =  $data['numInput'];

if($digit_key == substr($key, $numInput - 1, 1)){
    echo json_encode(array("valido" => "ok", "n" => $numInput));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("valido" => "error", "n" => $numInput));
}
```

and this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="actividad06.js" pe="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Actividad 6</title>
</head>
<body class="p-5">
<div id="checkCombination">
            <input type="number" id="input_compare1" onkeyup="compareValueKey(1)"><span class="msg"></span>
            <input type="number" id="input_compare2" onkeyup="compareValueKey(2)"><span class="msg"></span>
            <input type="number" id="input_compare3" onkeyup="compareValueKey(3)"><span class="msg"></span>
            <input type="number" id="input_compare4" onkeyup="compareValueKey(4)"><span class="msg"></span>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that there is an error in javascript code.

Could you be so kind to check?

Comment: Most likely $data is null. Please try `var_dump($data)` and provide the result if there is some. -> Try to debug `file_get_contents('php://input')` as well.

Comment: If PHP does not receive JSON as expected, provide a [example] including a reduced HTML code together with the JS code as a runnable bundle which is expected to produce the data. We don't see if there is any POST request and which data is actually sent.

Comment: @Pinke Helga,  I have added the html. It is reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not post a valid JSON format but you expect that in your PHP code. Your POST data is URL encoded instead.

The following line will give you a valid JSON string like `{ "digit_key" : "123", "numInput" : "456" }`

```
body: `{ "digit_key" : "${digit_key}", "numInput" : "${numInput}" }`,
```

Further more there is a type error in your PHP code. The `substr` function expects a string as argument 1, but an integer `$key = 1111` is given. You will run into an issue in newer PHP versions. For clean code use a string instead which will work with `strict_types` enabled as well:

```
$key = "1111";
```